# $_POST submit and URL in same button

Tags: php

Alright so this is my code:

```
    $vkey = $_POST['vkey'];
    if ($vkey == ""){
    $vkey = "-ieJtn73e1w";
    }
```

and my html

```
    <form method="POST" action="make.php">
    Youtube View Key eg:"fL9FmBKhyJs": <input type="text" name="vkey"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate">
```

What this does is generate a url like thing.php?vkey='' >THING.PHP ALREADY HAS $_GET THINGS FOR THIS, THIS ISN'T WHAT I'M ASKING ABOUT READ BELLOW.

When they click submit I want it to auto redirect them to thing.php?vkey=''

I've tried to

```
    onclick="location.href='thing.php?vkey=<?php echo $vkey; ?>'"
```

this works for a separate button bellow after the submit button is clicked but I want it all in one button.

Comment: Why don't you simply change the action to `action="thing.php"`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a normal input button as your submit button? You could try this:

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="submit();window.location='thing.php?vkey=<?php echo $vkey; ?>'" />
```

If the variables are being excluded when you use that code, I would suggest replacing the button's code with this:

```
<?php echo "<input type='button' value='submit' onClick='submit();window.location=\'thing.php?vkey=".$vkey."\'' />" ?>
```

What that would do is echo the button to the page, making it a little bit easier to include the variable in the url by keeping it all in the php echo. The code should be right before the closing `</form>` tag.

Comment: Well that kind of works but it leaves out the variables when echoed lel.

Comment: Sorry about that, i think i found the error. See my edit. I changed to `window.location` instead of `location.href`

Comment: Hmm, okay let me look into that, just a minute.

Comment: variables are still left blank :c

Comment: Try echoing the vkey variable, are you sure it contains a value?

Comment: Welp, I managed to fix this myself. #newtophp but it works.


        <form method="GET" action="thing.php">
        Name:<span style="color: red;">*</span> <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
        Message:<span style="color: red;">*</span> <input type="text" name="msg"><br><br>
        Youtube View Key eg:"fL9FmBKhyJs": <input type="text" name="vkey"><br><br>
        Imgur Image Key eg:"wwi9smO.jpg": <input type="text" name="img"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>